# How to remove an item at a given index from Array/List in Elm?

Tags: arrays, list, elm

What is the most elegant way to remove an item at index `i` in a given `Array`? In a given `List`?

Answer (score 18):

Best I could think of:

```
removeFromList i xs =
  (List.take i xs) ++ (List.drop (i+1) xs) 

removeFromArray i =
  Array.toList >> removeFromList i >> Array.fromList
```

Comment: Beaten by 1 minute! Also you can drop the parens.

Comment: The sort state of the list is irrelevant as the question was related to the position in the list (index) not the characteristics of the element in the list. It can also be a list of unsortable items.

Answer (score 7):

This should be pretty efficient:

```
remove : Int -> Array a -> Array a
remove i a =
  let
    a1 = Array.slice 0 i a
    a2 = Array.slice (i+1) (Array.length a) a
  in
    Array.append a1 a2
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `List.Extra.removeAt` from [elm-community](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/7.1.0/List-Extra#removeAt).

Answer (score 2):

I needed an `indexedFilter` function recently. This could provide you a fold based alternative

```
indexedFilter : (Int -> a -> Bool) -> List a -> List a
indexedFilter p xs =
    let
        tup = List.map2 (,) [ 0 .. List.length xs - 1 ] xs
    in List.foldr (\(i,x) acc -> if p i x then x :: acc else acc) [] tup
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different kind of solution based on J's [`from`](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/curlylf#dyadic).

Usage:

```
[-1,2,0] `from` ["fran","world","san","hello"]
```

which returns: `[Just "hello",Just "san",Just "fran"]`

Definition, after `import List exposing (..)`:

```
get idx lst =  -- get an element from a list (negative indexes from end)
  if idx >= 0 then
    head (drop idx lst)
  else
    head (drop (negate (idx+1)) (reverse lst))

from idxs lst =  -- atoms of idxs are indexes into lst
  case idxs of
    hd::tl -> (get hd lst)::(from tl lst)
    _ -> []
```

Answer (score 0):

The "elm-community/array-extra" package now provides this function:

https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/array-extra/2.1.0/Array-Extra#removeAt